# Downcasing an array with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an application that uses Ruby and I can get this to work.
What I can't do is the same filter but just with upcase or downcase so I don't have to list all possible options.

```
files = input_value

files.reject!{|f|
f.match(/MXF|mxf|MOV|mov|MP4|mp4|3G2|3g2|3GP|3gp|ASF|asf|AVI|avi|F4V|f4v|FLV|flv|M4V|m4v|M2TS|m2ts|MKV|mkv|MPEG|mpeg|MPG|mpg|MPV|mpv|MTS|mts|OGV|ogv|SVI|svi|VOB|vob|WEBM|webm|WMV|wmv|WAV|wav|MP3|mp3/).blank?
}
```

Comment: What happens if you get `mov.jpeg`? Wouldn't it be better to use `File.extname` to extract the extension, downcase it, and do a simple array inclusion test?

Comment: show me what you mean and I'll try it. Not everything works in my Ruby app.

Comment: See Cary's answer below, that's pretty much what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For improved efficiency, I suggest you create a set containing the desired file extensions. Determining if a set contains a given element takes about the same time as determining if a hash has a given key. It's much faster than stepping through an array.

```
require 'set'

BAD_EXT = %w| mxf mov mp4 3g2 3gp asf avi f4v flv m4v m2ts mkv
              mpeg mpg mpv mts ogv svi vob webm wmv wav mp3 |.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {"mxf", "mov", "mp4", "3g2", "3gp", "asf", "avi", "f4v",
  #           "flv", "m4v", "m2ts", "mkv", "mpeg", "mpg", "mpv", "mts",
  #           "ogv", "svi", "vob", "webm", "wmv", "wav", "mp3"}> 

fnames = ["./Ruby/Cat.mov", "./Ruby/Dog.woof", "./Ruby/pig"]

fnames.select { |fname| BAD_EXT.include?(File.extname(fname).downcase.sub(/\A\./, "")) }
  #=> ["./Ruby/Cat.mov"]
```

See [File::extname](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/File.html#method-c-extname).

Note:

```
File.extname("abc.def")
  #=> ".def" 
File.extname("abc")
  #=> ""
```

Hence the need to remove the period if one is present (`...sub(/\A\./, "")`).

The OP evidently wants to `select` files with those extensions. See comment below.

Comment: I'm building a white list and need to return the original values without any case changes. 
I only want the media files with these extensions.
Does using fnames.reject! return the opposite?

Comment: Yes, you need `select` or `select!`. (I suggest the former unless you have good reason to modify the array of file names in place.) Both those methods will here return the original file name. I changed my example slightly to show that.

Comment: This brought me to a final solution. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `i` (for case-insensitive, I suppose) option for regex

```
files.reject! do |f|
  f.match /mxf|mov|mp4|3g2|3gp|asf|avi|f4v|flv|m4v|m2ts|mkv|mpeg|mpg|mpv|mts|ogv|svi|vob|webm|wmv|wav|mp3/i
end
```

Comment: I added the tweaks my app needs and based on your suggestion, it worked. Thank You

files = input_value files.reject!{|f| f.match(/mxf|mov|mp4|3g2|3gp|asf|avi|f4v|flv|m4v|m2ts|mkv|mpeg|mpg|mpv|mts|ogv|svi|vob|webm|wmv|wav|mp3/i).blank?}

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)